# Getting the number of 200 and 500 request in appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get the number of 200 and other codes from my appengine using the metrics explorer. Is there a way to get this? I keep getting 1 and 2

Comment: What have you tried to far? Where are you getting 1 and 2? Are you running queries in Log Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Google Cloud Platform console, go to Logging > Logs Explorer, and run the following query, specifying the time range you are interested in.

```
(protoPayload.status=200 OR httpRequest.status=200)
resource.type="gae_app"
```

The same applies for errors 500.

```
(protoPayload.status=500 OR httpRequest.status=500)
resource.type="gae_app"
```